# JMS Consumer terminates and doesn't receive Message

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jms

So I'm following [this](https://youtu.be/0wIpMyHuOO8?list=PLA80A2255382AFC98) youtube tutorial on Java Message Service with JBoss. My codes are the same to the video however when I run my `TopicConsumer` and `TopicProducer` applications, both terminates and don't stay alive for me to receive my message. I read that `setMessageListener` would have created a new thread so the message should be received even if the main thread was terminated but I'm still not receiving the message.

I found out that it's not calling `onMessage`, is it because `TopicConsumer` was terminated before it gets a chance to?

I've my JBoss 5.0 server running, just like in the video I run `TopicConsumer` first (but it terminates after the print statement unlike in the video) then `TopicProduver` (which also terminates right after the print statement) and I don't receive my message.

Thanks.

TopicConsumer.java

```
package jmspubsubtutorial;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.jms.Topic;
import javax.jms.TopicConnection;
import javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.TopicSession;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class TopicConsumer implements MessageListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException, NamingException{
        System.out.println("---Starting TopicConsumer---");
        Context context = TopicConsumer.getInitialContext();
        TopicConnectionFactory topicConnectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) context.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
        Topic topic = (Topic) context.lookup("topic/JMS_tutorial");
        TopicConnection topicConnection = topicConnectionFactory.createTopicConnection();
        TopicSession topicSession = topicConnection.createTopicSession(false, TopicSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        topicSession.createSubscriber(topic).setMessageListener(new TopicConsumer());
        topicConnection.start();

        System.out.println("---Exiting TopicConsumer---");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.println("--- onMessage ---");
        try {
            System.out.println("Incoming message: " + ((TextMessage)message).getText());
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            System.out.println("onMessage failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Context getInitialContext() throws JMSException, NamingException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "localhost:1099");
        Context context = new InitialContext(props);
        return context;
    }
}
```

TopicProducer.java

```
package jmspubsubtutorial;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.jms.Topic;
import javax.jms.TopicConnection;
import javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.TopicPublisher;
import javax.jms.TopicSession;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class TopicProducer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException, NamingException{
        System.out.println("---Starting TopicProducer---");
        Context context = TopicConsumer.getInitialContext();
        TopicConnectionFactory topicConnectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) context.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
        Topic topic = (Topic) context.lookup("topic/JMS_tutorial");
        TopicConnection topicConnection = topicConnectionFactory.createTopicConnection();
        TopicSession topicSession = topicConnection.createTopicSession(false, TopicSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        topicConnection.start();
        TopicProducer topicProducer = new TopicProducer();
        String text = "message 1 from TopicProducer...";
        topicProducer.sendMessage(text, topicSession, topic);

        System.out.println("---Exiting TopicProducer---");
    }

    public void sendMessage(String text, TopicSession topicSession, Topic topic) throws JMSException {
        System.out.println("Send Message: " + text + " " + topicSession + " " + topic);
        TopicPublisher topicPublisher = topicSession.createPublisher(topic);
        TextMessage textMessage = topicSession.createTextMessage(text);
        topicPublisher.publish(textMessage);
        topicPublisher.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that you are relying on the JMS library to maintain at least one non-daemon thread in order to keep your application alive after you create the consumer and assign the message listener but in reality there is no guarantee that it will do any such thing.

It's true that many JMS providers do indeed attempt to always have a single non-daemon thread running internally but assuming that this will always be the case is not really advisable.  You've seemed to find that the your particular provider does not do this for you, so if you want to ensure your application stays running you should make this happen yourself.